# My model instance is not getting created in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am working on an application that registers energy-usage(water, gas, electricity) for Users. A user can have more than one homes and each home can have more usages(year1, year2, year3).

On my User detail page I have a 'tab' for each home and in this tab there is also a button for adding a new usage.

I am trying to open this 'new-use' form in a modal, via remote => true. This button adds two parameters with the request :use_year and :home_id.

In my controller use/new I am creating a new use instance '@use' and try to pass the two url parameters to the corresponding attributes via an assignment.

And this just don't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I cant assign a value to an attribute of this new instance of @use. Tried to do this in the rails console and that works fine. What am I doing wrong?

#### usescontroller.rb

```
def new
  myparams = use_new_params
  use_year = myparams[:use_year].to_i
  home_id = myparams[:home_id].to_i

  @use = Use.new do |u|
    u.use_year = 2016 #use_year
    u.home_id = 25 # home_id
  end

  @home = Home.find(home_id)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js 
    end 
end



private

def use_new_params
  params.require(:usage).permit(:use_year,:home_id)
end
```

This is the part where the button is

#### View.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 
    "+ usage ",
    new_use_path(:usage => {:home_id => home.id, :use_year => 2016 }),
    :class => 'btn btn-primary pull-xs-right', 
    :remote => true %>
```

And this is my Use model

#### Use.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: uses
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  use_year    :integer
#  gas_1       :float
#  gas_1_sum   :float
#  gas_2       :float
#  gas_2_sum   :float
#  water_1     :float
#  water_1_sum :float
#  water_2     :float
#  water_2_sum :float
#  elec_1      :float
#  elec_1_sum  :float
#  elec_2      :float
#  elec_2_sum  :float
#  extra_info  :string
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#

class Use < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :home

end
```

#### my logfile:

```
Started GET "/uses/new?usage%5Bhome_id%5D=24&usage%5Buse_year%5D=2016" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-23 10:52:18 +0200
Processing by UsesController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"usage"=>{"home_id"=>"24", "use_year"=>"2016"}}
  Person Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "people"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Home Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "homes".* FROM "homes" WHERE "homes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  Rendered uses/_errors.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered uses/_useForm.html.erb (454.1ms)
  Rendered uses/new.js.erb (456.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 480ms (Views: 462.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

[image]

This is a screenshot from my IDE. The attribute value for use_year should have a value, but is nil.

Comment: Is there any error? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: can you post your server log after you made the request?

Comment: added a piece of log-file: from clicking the button till showing modal

Comment: I suspect the output from your ide is misleading you - `@values` is just some internal ActiveRecord concern. If you want to check what is set, then check what `@use.use_year` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of Frederick is found out this was not where the problem was.

Thanks!